# Query compound _id for time range in MongoDB using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query, compound-index

I have a collection in which the `_id`s are compound of a time and an string (yeah, I know it's bad but... *it was like that when I arrived*). One record in that collection looks like:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "my_string": "Foo",
    "my_time": new Date("2014-12-19T12:38:00-0500")
  },
  "field1": 60,
  "field2": 17,
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to figure out a query which would give me the records where `_id.my_string` is `Foo` and `_id.my_time` is between `time1` and `time2`

Can I use `$and` to build a query `dict` querying different parts of the compound `_id`?

This returns 0 records:

```
my_collection.find(
    {
        '_id': {
            'my_string': 'Foo',
            '$and': [
                {'my_time': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(...)}},
                {'my_time': {'$lte': datetime.datetime(...)}},
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

So does this this:

```
 my_collection.find(
    {'$and': [
        {'_id':
            {
                'my_string': "Foo"
                'my_time': {'$lte': datetime.datetime(...)}
            }
         },
        {'_id':
            {
                'my_string': "Foo",
                'my_time': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(...)}
            }
         },
        ]
     }
```

Just in case you haven't noticed, I'm a real newbie when it comes to MongoDB.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_collection.find(
    {
        '$and' :
            [
                {'_id.my_string': 'Foo'},
                {'_id.my_time' : {'$gte': datetime.datetime(...), '$lte': datetime.datetime(...)}},
            ]
        }
    }
    )
```

You do not need to use [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and) for this query.

The following query can be written as:

```
my_collection.find(
    {
        '_id.my_string': 'Foo',
        '_id.my_time' : 
        {
            '$gte': datetime.datetime(...), 
            '$lte': datetime.datetime(...)
        }
    }
    )
```